# Database-migration ms sql to postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am getting a syntax error when converting between SQL Server to PostgreSQL. Any thoughts?

```
IF (var_port_with_bmrk_total_mv != 0 AND var_bmrk_info IS NOT NULL) THEN
    BEGIN
        insert into t$tmp_diff
                select @asof_dt asof_dt,@choiceID choiceID ,p.input_array_type ,p.group_order, CONVERT(DECIMAL(32,10),p.port_value/@var_port_total_mv) port_value,convert(decimal(32,10), isnull(bmrk_value/@port_with_bmrk_total_mv,0)) bmrk_value
                from  t$tmp_port_sum p, t$tmp_bmrk_sum b
                where p.input_array_type=b.input_array_type and p.group_order = b.group_order
    END;
ELSE
```

Original before conversion

```
insert into #tmp_other_diff 
select @asof_dt asof_dt,@choiceID choiceID , b.input_array_type,b.grouping,convert(decimal(32,10),0)  port_value, (bmrk_value/@port_with_bmrk_total_mv) bmrk_value
from   #tmp_bmrk_other_sum b
where  b.key_value not in ( select p.key_value from #tmp_port_other_sum p)
```

Error message:

Error occurred during SQL query execution

> Reason:
> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
> Position: 9030

the relevant comma being:

```sql
CONVERT(DECIMAL(32,10),p.port_value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `convert()` function in Postgres. Use the SQL standard `cast` or the Postgres extension `::data type`. In this case:

```
...., cast(0 as decimal(30,10)) port_value, .... 
     OR 
...., 0::decimal(30,10) port_value, ...
```

Note: No comma after the expression. In the original port_value is the column alias. You need to keep it that way.